# Logback configuration error detected

Tags: logging, logback

i used logback in my spring boot project, when i run the project i get this logback error

> ```
>  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected:  
>  ERROR in c.q.l.c.recovery.ResilientFileOutputStream@134367664 - IO  
>  failure while writing to file [logs\project\serviceProvider.log]  
>  java.io.IOException: Stream Closed  
>      at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:162)  
>      at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.reinitialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:208)  
>      at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initializeWithConventions(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:74)  
>      at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initialize(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:59)  
>      at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.initialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:115)  
>      at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:303)  
>      at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:276)  
>      at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:239)  
>      at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:212)  
>      at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:167)  
>      at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)  
>      at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:122)  
>      at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:74)  
>      at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)  
>      at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:325)  
>      at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:296)  
>      at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120)  
>      at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)  
>      at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)  
>      at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)  
>      at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)  
>      at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)  
>      at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:44)  
>      at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)  
>      at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)   
>     at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)  
>      at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)  
>      at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)  
>      at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)  
>      at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)  
>      at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)  
>      at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)  
>      at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)  
>      at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)  
>      at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)  
>      at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)  
>      at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)  
>      at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)  
>      at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)  
>      at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)  
>      at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)  
>      at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)  
>      at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)  
>      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  
>      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)  
>      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)  
>      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)  
>      at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)  
>      at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)  
>      at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:172)  
>      at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:104)  
>      at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:70)
> ```

```
<configuration>
    <property name="LOG_HOME" value="logs" />

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-5.5p] [%thread] [%-20.20C:%-5.5L] %msg%n</Pattern>
        </layout>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>INFO</level>
        </filter>
    </appender>

    <appender name="SERVICE-PROVIDER-LOG" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOG_HOME}/project/serviceProvider.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_HOME}/project/archived/serviceProvider-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.gz
            </fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
            <totalSizeCap>1GB</totalSizeCap>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-5.5p] [%thread] [%-20.20C:%-5.5L] %msg%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.project.serviceprovider.back" level="TRACE" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="SERVICE-PROVIDER-LOG" />
    </logger>

    <root level="TRACE">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="SERVICE-PROVIDER-LOG" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Sounds like `logs\project` might be full or your process does not have write access to `logs\project\`. I don't think this is a Logback issue _per se_.